# Wiring power to many LED Strands

Tags: power-supply, led, circuit-design, wiring

I have read as many threads on this site and others related to this, but haven't found any that specifically answers my questions.

I have about 20 WS2811 LED Strands. They are 12V and each LED uses about 0.6 watts so 600 watts for the entire 1000.

So, that would mean 600W at 12V is 50amps. However, many people say you need to apply power every so often due to voltage drop.

But is it really as simple as attaching them end to end with a power supply that is 12V at greater than 50 amps? If I want to apply power to multiple entry points along the massive strand, how do I split off the power from the supply to each point?

If I used a power supply like this [image: one]

Does each split to supply power need to come from another one of the V+?

Is there a better way to connect all these strands together?

Comment: You can put multiple wires onto each power supply terminal or run a single positive and a single negative wire that goes the length of the strips connecting to them every few meters.

Comment: For a 50 A total load, I would split the load into three parts so I could use all three pairs of output terminals on the supply.

Comment: So with a power supply, if you use all three parts, does the current split 3 ways as well? Or does each still receive the full load of say 50amps?

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/423480/2028

Comment: Also related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings

Comment: Current is what the load will use full out, if it doesn't need it it will not draw it. By splitting the load out several ways you are spreading the load across several wires each carrying approximately the same current but this is dependent on wire size,percentage of load and wire length. The power supply will deliver anywhere from 0 to 50 watts, what the load draws. If you used a 100A power supply for example a 50 Watt load will only draw 50 watts and the power supply will probably run cooler.

Comment: @RyanWilson the 3 parts are most likely just connected together - it's not 3 parts, it's 1 part with 3 screws to make it easier to attach 3 wires if you want to.